# CSS Grids Empty Space Left Before An Element That Would Fit In It

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Hi guys I could not find any helping examples since I have never used CSS grids, anyways how would I fill the empty space in the grid with next element? My `1fr` element does not fit in the previous space that is available. Is it due to that I'm doubling the height of the class or what?
Like I've said I have never used CSS grids but I only need them now and this is the last thing I would add to the code, could you guys help me out?

```css
#container {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  float: left;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
}

#container>div:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.content-1x,
.content-2x,
.content-3x {
  margin: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
  height: 15rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.double-height {
  height: 30rem;
}

.content-3x {
  grid-area: auto / auto / auto / span 3;
}

.content-2x {
  grid-area: auto / auto / auto / span 2;
}

.content-1x {
  grid-area: auto / auto / auto / span 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content-3x">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="content-2x double-height">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="content-1x">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="content-1x">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="content-2x">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="content-1x">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="content-2x">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="content-3x">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="content-2x">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="content-1x">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="content-1x">
    9
  </div>
  <div class="content-2x">
    10
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any easy way to do this without using media queries or sth like that?

Comment: Try with `grid-auto-flow: dense`

Comment: on the #container element? if yes, have tried and nothing

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly is the problem here ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377343/3597276

Comment: Something like this I suppose [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swordys/dwd9c2tk)

Answer (score 5):

Try this, add

```
grid-auto-flow:dense; to grid container
```

> This attempts to fill in holes earlier in the grid, if smaller items
>   come up later. This may cause items to appear out-of-order, when doing
>   so would fill in holes left by larger items.

Also for **.doubleheight**, u r adding height to it, but u r not telling the grid layout that u are occupying that much space, this is necessary because, other divs position depends on it. U can do this by adding

```
   .double-height {
      height: 31rem;
      grid-row: span 2!important;
      grid-column: span 2!important;
    }
```

This code tells, the double-height div to go 2 columns to the right from its own position, and go 2 rows down from its own position.

```css
#container {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  float: left;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
}

#container>div:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.content-1x,
.content-2x,
.content-3x {
  margin: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
  height: 15rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.double-height {
  height: 31rem;
  grid-row: span 2!important;
  grid-column: span 2!important;
}

.content-3x {
  grid-area: auto / auto / auto / span 3;
}

.content-2x {
  grid-area: auto / auto / auto / span 2;
}

.content-1x {
  grid-area: auto / auto / auto / span 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="content-3x">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="content-2x double-height">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="content-1x">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="content-1x">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="content-2x">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="content-1x">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="content-2x">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="content-3x">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="content-2x">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="content-1x">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="content-1x">
    9
  </div>
  <div class="content-2x">
    10
  </div>
</div>
```